# STM32 Read mic value (MP34DT05-A) from I2S DMA

Tags: stm32, pcm, dma, i2s

I want to read MEMS microphone (MP34DT05-A) value (in ASCII) from STM32F107 board. I'm using I2S to communicate with the microphone.

What I did:

- I tried simple reading with `HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA(&hi2s3, i2sbuffer, 100);` which `uint16_t i2sbuffer[256];` and the result is random character (`E⸮h2FI⸮g⸮⸮F⸮⸮⸮`).
- I'm using `PDM_Filter` from `pdm2pcm_glo.h` (`STM32_Audio\Addons\PDM library`):

```
HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA(&hi2s3, pdm_buff, 16);
PDM_Filter(&cbuff[0], &pcm_buff[0], &PDM1_filter_handler);
```

and the result still random character (`d⸮⸮l⸮巳⸮N#⸮&6⸮4q٣⸮#⸮d⸮ɻ&⸮}⸮`).

Should I need conversion for the data? Or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PDM microphone does not output ASCII!

The PDM microphone outputs a sequence of 1-bit values.

The function PDM_Filter converts it to PCM, which is a sequence of 16-bit values, still in binary.

To print the 16 bit sequence as text, you would need to do something like:

```
printf("%hi,", pcm_buff[0]);
printf("%hi,", pcm_buff[1]);
...
```

but obviously you can use a loop.

Comment: In which bit I can use to measurement? Or is there any other method? I want to use it as sound trigger.